# javascript - why is 'this' not referencing the object? code below

Tags: javascript, scope

I don't understand why `this.name` isn't the same as `obj.name`, basically why in this case `this` refers to the `window` object and not the `obj` object. In the code below, `this.name` is instantiated after `obj.name`..

```
function createNewPerson(name) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.name = name;
    alert(this.name);
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it would? `obj` is just an object (even if this was a called as a method on an instance, `this` would still not reference `obj`). You should read up on the this keyword for a basic understanding. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 1):

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this):

> Inside a function, the value of this depends on how the function is
>   called. Since the following code is not in strict mode, and because
>   the value of this is not set by the call, this will default to the
>   global object , which is window in a browser.

So in your case you have `this` as the Window object, not the `obj`. You may get the `obj` context inside your function via binding it manually, for example:

```
function createNewPerson(name) {
  console.log(this.name); // Hello
  console.log(name); // World
}

var obj = {};
obj.name = 'Hello';
var salva = createNewPerson.apply(obj, ['World']);
```

But what you really need, as I can understand, is a function cunstructor and instantiating an object via `new` operator:

```
function createNewPerson(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
var salva = new createNewPerson('Salva');
console.log(salva.name); // Salva
```